# How do I parse the body of a request using the http module in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, http

I am trying to write a framework for Node without using any Express code. I want to be able to get the body from a HTTP request using the http module, but nothing I try seems to work. This is my code currently:

```
import http from "http";
import url from "url";
import Route from "./Route";
import HTTPRequest from "./HTTPRequest";

class HextecCreator {
  static createApp = (routes: Array<Route>) => {
    return {
      getRoutes: () => {
        return routes;
      },
      run: (port: number) => {
        http
          .createServer(function (req, res) {
            let data: any = [];
            req
              .on("data", (chunk) => data.push(chunk))
              .on("end", () => {
                data = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
              });
            var correctRoute;
            for (var route of routes) {
              if (route.getUrl() === req.url) {
                correctRoute = route;
                break;
              } else {
                correctRoute = "Route not found";
              }
            }

            if (typeof correctRoute != "object") {
              res.write("Route not found");
              res.end();
            } else {
              res.write(
                correctRoute
                  .getHandlerFunc()(
                    new HTTPRequest(
                      req.method,
                      req.url,
                      url.parse(req.url as string, true).query,
                      data
                    )
                  )
                  .getResponse()
              );
              res.end();
            }
          })
          .listen(port);
      },
    };
  };
}

export default HextecCreator;
```

This should work, but when I use postman to actually get the body of the request, it is empty. How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe you must force a wait for `.getResponse()` either with a promise, async/await or a callback. Or else it'll just continue to res.end before anything gets written.

Answer (score 0):

The `end` event gets triggered after your entire function is complete. To to do something with the entire HTTP request body, you will need to trigger this functionality from within the `end` handler.

This means that the rest of your logic needs to live inside the `end` event handler, or you need to call a function that "does the rest", but still from within that `end` event.

I also wrote a framework from scratch, and this is my async/await based version:

https://github.com/curveball/core/blob/master/src/node/request.ts#L36

Note that this still delegates turning an entire stream to a buffer to an external package.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps!